# Why can't I cast from any[] to MyType[] in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, casting, typescript, any

TypeScript has an `any` type that any and every arbitrary type can be cast TO OR FROM. I can cast from a variable of type `any` to a variable of type `MyArbitraryType` like in

```
var myThing: MyArbitraryType;
var anyThing: any;
...
myThing = anyThing;//implicit cast from 'any' to 'MyArbitraryType'
//or
myThing = <MyArbitraryType>anyThing;//explicit cast from 'any' to 'MyArbitraryType'
```

But I get an error when I try to cast from an `any[]` to a `MyArbitraryType[]` like in

```
var myThings: MyArbitraryType[];
var anyThings: any[];
...
myThings = anyThings;//implicit cast from 'any[]' to 'MyArbitraryType[]'
//or
myThings = <MyArbitraryType[]>anyThings;//explicit cast from 'any[]' to 'MyArbitraryType[]'
```

However I CAN do it if I use `any` as a middle-man like in

```
myThings = <MyArbitraryType[]><any>anyThings;
```

Which I could just use as is, but feels kinda sloppy. Is there a reason that `any` is castable to and from any type but `any[]` isn't castable to and from any array? Is this just an oversight in TypeScript so far? Or is there some other syntax I'm unaware of?

Comment: Why do you say this doesn't work? According to the playground it does: http://bit.ly/1cQDpA5 (note: I copied your code above and added a class defining MyArbitraryType)

Comment: You're right; it seems that it wasn't actually a typescript compile error as far as the actual typescript compiler is concerned, but rather an error being generated only by Resharper. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. It was Resharper, not the actual Typescript compiler, that was generating the error.